# Trying to make name-based virtual hosts work on apache2 with self hosted DNS not working

Tags: linux, networking, dns, apache-http-server

I'm reading a book on Ubuntu Server and after wiring all the networking, DHCP, DNS, NTP and all, we got to the point where we need to create an apache2 web-server.

I followed all the instructions but when we got to the **multiple virtual host** part, I can't seem to make it work.

Having only one network interface, I opted for the **named-based virtual hosts**.
I'm going to list all my DHCP, DNS and Apache2 configurations to make it easy for everyone to figure the problem out.

**DHCP**

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
default-lease-time 43200;
max-lease-time 86400;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option domain-name "local.lan";
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.240;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
}
```

**DNS**

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        forwarders {
          8.8.8.8;
          8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "local.lan" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/net.local.lan";
};
```

/etc/bind/net.local.lan

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA local.lan. exampleemail.local.lan. (

202212152; serial

8H ; refresh
4H ; retry
4W ; expire
1D ) ; minimum
IN A 192.168.1.1
;
@ IN NS lenovo.local.lan.
lenovo     IN  A   192.168.1.1 #my server
```

**WEBSITE**

For the website configuration, I created a file called `000-virtual-hosts.conf` that holds the config for the virtual hosts I want to make work.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-virtual-hosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myotherwebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myotherwebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myotherwebsite_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Call me a noob, but I don't know if the reason it doesn't work is because I don't own the `mywebsite.com` and `myotherwebsite.com` domains but I thought it would follow the example in the book and the domains would be requested specifically through port 80 and add the resolve to my server IP further in this post it would be local no matter if I own the domains or not.
I thought it could be the fact that they're pointing to the same `/var/www/html` file and that could be the problem.
I enabled them before I tried to make it work, `sudo a2ensite 000-virtual-hosts.conf` && `sudo systemctl reload apache2`.

The book at one point says: "*If you're using domain names with virtual hosts, then this will only work if you set up networking such that the domain name referenced in the file resolves to the IP address of your server. [...] If you're running your own DNS server, you would add the A record there.*"
So I added this line to `/etc/bind/net.local.lan` and updated the `serial` number, otherwise the DNS wouldn't accept the new host.

```
mywebsite.com IN A 192.168.1.247
```

But I think the problem is I really don't know what I'm doing/doing wrong.

Here are the logs caught by `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I don't know if those logs could include connection failures to `mywebsite.com` because they're supposed to be for the default `.conf` file but I'm sharing them in case you need them.

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Dec 16 01:32:24.187718 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32022:tid 139897582640192] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**EDIT**

I changed my `/etc/bind/net.local.net`

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA local.lan. exampleemail.local.lan. (

202212154; serial

8H ; refresh
4H ; retry
4W ; expire
1D ) ; minimum
IN A 192.168.1.1
;
@ IN NS lenovo.local.lan.
lenovo     IN  A   192.168.1.1
mywebsite IN A 192.168.1.247
myotherwebsite IN A 192.168.1.247
```

I've made both website resolve to the same IP because in the book it says: "*Any traffic coming into the server requesting "mywebsite" will be provided /var/www/mywebsite, the second example looks for traffic from "myotherwebsite" and directs hits to /var/www/myotherwebsite*".

and disabled the default file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` that was taking the IP of the server.

Now the new page shows, but it doesn't make a difference when I type `mywebsite` or `mywebsite.local.lan` it doesn't find it but `IP:80` works.

I still don't know how to type `mywebsite` and reach the local page.

**Results of the dig command**

**mywebsite.local.lan**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> mywebsite.local.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 17696
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mywebsite.local.lan.           IN      A

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 21 12:02:17 PST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

**myotherwebsite.local.lan**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> myotherwebsite.local.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 59264
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myotherwebsite.local.lan.      IN      A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 21 12:02:19 PST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

I get almost the same output from another computer on the network, just the `udp` number changes.

Comment: Is the DNS server at 192.168.1.247 or is it at 192.168.1.1?

Comment: The DNS server is at 192.168.1.1

Comment: Do the domain names resolve to the web server's IP address?

Comment: If you're asking for example if I owned the domains and made them resolve to it from a website like godaddy, no. But in my example I've added the resolution, or at least what I think is one, to the `/etc/bind/net.local.lan` as you can see in the line `mywebsite.com IN A 192.168.1.247` to create a "local" resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the configuration you posted, your DNS server doesn't have any records that would point `mywebsite.com.` or `myotherwebsite.com.` to the Apache webserver – it doesn't even have a matching zone configured for those names – so all it does is forward the queries to the "upstream" servers (8.8.8.8, etc).

Currently the DNS server is only set up to host one domain – you have `zone "local.lan" {..}`, so *everything* in the specified zonefile is assumed to be under the "`local.lan`" domain. Any "out-of-zone" records in that file would be rejected.

A zonefile entry of `mywebsite.com IN A ...` doesn't create a domain "mywebsite.com" – due to the missing final `.` it has $ORIGIN automatically appended to it, so just like the "lenovo" entry becomes "lenovo.local.lan.", the "mywebsite.com" entry **becomes "mywebsite.com.local.lan."** (which is why it didn't get rejected outright by BIND as an out-of-zone name).

(Because your DHCP server broadcasts `option domain-name "local.lan"`, *some* client devices will try to look up "mywebsite.com.local.lan." when the user enters "http:‍//mywebsite.com/", but the majority of them won't do that – if the user input already has at least one dot, the DHCP-provided domain suffix won't be appended. Meaning, the entry in your "local.lan" zone will never be queried.)

To make BIND answer for the domain name "mywebsite.com", you literally need a `zone{}` entry that matches this domain, e.g. `zone "com"` or `zone "mywebsite.com"`, with its own zonefile.

(Alternatively, BIND's RPZ `response-policy{}` mechanism could be used to spoof replies for various domains without creating individual zones for each.)

Comment: Man thank you so much, you made me understand the concept of zones and DNS a lot more now. thank you so much.

Comment: I still have a problem tho, I edited my answer, I still can't reach `mywwebsite` whether I type `mywebsite.local.lan` or `mywebsite.local.lan:80`

Comment: Then I still ask the same question:  Do the domain names _actually_ resolve to the web server's IP address? What results do you get from trying to resolve them with a DNS query tool (dig, drill, nslookup, host, etc)?

Comment: It was my understanding that if I added the line `mywebsite IN A 192.168.1.247` and modified apache's `sites-available`  `.conf` file's `ServerName` to remove the `.com` from the domain `mywebsite`, it would resolve to the server if I typed it in a web browser. It kind of does because I disabled the default file and only have the virtual hosts enabled with different html pages and it hits one of the two new html but not by their domain name, only by typing the local IP. I tried with dig on the same laptop that the DNS server is on and it worked with the IP but not with `mywebsite`.

Comment: What's the output of `dig mywebsite.local.lan` from the laptop? And is the laptop actually configured to *use* itself as the DNS server?

Comment: Apache is completely irrelevant at this point – it cannot "attract" requests to itself; domain name resolution to an address is handled only by DNS, and what you put in /etc/apache only defines what happens _after_ the domain resolution is done and the HTTP request has already reached Apache. So if DNS is not working, you need to ignore Apache and ignore web browsers and investigate DNS instead.

Comment: I've added the output of `dig mywebsite.local.lan` to the `Edit` part of my answer and yes it should use itself as a DNS server as it says in the book "bind9 should report that it's active (running). [...] you should now have a working DNS server." and I've followed it closely. However the next section says "all you need to do is configure other devices on your network to use your DNS server." and I tried to load the website from another device so if my other devices are not configured to use it that could be a reason but I'm not sure. the default local website works with the other device.

Comment: Yes, you should now have a working DNS server, but that doesn't imply that devices will automatically start _using_ it. That's why the book says "you need to configure devices to use your DNS server". For most other devices that's handled by DHCP – they get the `option domain-name-servers` parameter from the DHCP server – but the server _itself_ doesn't get DHCP from itself, so it still needs to be manually configured to use its own address, either through resolv.conf or (in your case) through systemd-resolved.

Comment: Without that configuration, you can still tell dig/nslookup to use a custom server address, e.g. `dig mywebsite.local.lan A @192.168.1.1`, to verify whether that server works.

Comment: I see. Does that mean that first off I should set a static IP for my DNS server through `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` that's outside the scope of automatically assigned IPs ?

Comment: So I think my DNS set up is a mess, I'm watching a bunch of videos and it seems like either I'm missing a configuration somewhere or I haven't done something. I'm figuring out what the problem is and I'll report as soon as I find something.

Comment: Are you saying the DNS server's IP address _isn't_ the one that your DHCP has been advertising through `option domain-name-servers`? If not, then yes, it definitely needs some sort of static address so that you could put it in the DHCP server's configuration.

Comment: Yes, I've added `option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;` when my server's IP, though not static, is `192.168.1.247`. so I think I didn't really understand the concept of name servers properly and just added the default values from the book instead of knowing what I was doing. I'll make the changes and comment again to let you know if it worked. Thank you so much for putting time and effort into this you're awesome.

Comment: I understand what the problem is. I didn't understand how DNS worked at all, so I was confused. Whether I wanted a .com or else I needed to create a zone for it as you said, I didn't really know what a zone was, a nameserver or even how any of it worked with one another. Now I get it and therefore I understand that if I have my own DNS I need to add a zone .com and point the IP to the server as an A record, and make the DHCP server point its NS option to the DNS server. Then add the apache VH's domains to their zone file. Thank you for helping.